# Can I identify a class/set of unitary matrices only knowing a single eigenvector of these matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the eigenvalue equation $Uv=v$. Here $U$ is a unitary matrix and $v$ is a known eigenvector with eigenvalue 1.

I know that this equation doesn't $\textit{uniquely}$ define $U$, but I was wondering what statements I can make about the unitary matrices which obey the above equation.

I suspect that there is an $\textit{infinite}$ amount of matrices $U$ that share this specific eigenvector but I am struggling to prove this.

Is it possible to find an expression which restricts the set of all unitary matrices to a subset fulfilling $Uv=v$?

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By rotating your basis, you can assume that $v = (1,0,\ldots,0)$. $Uv = v$ now implies $U_{1,1} = 1$ and $U_{n,1} = 0$ for $n \geq 2$. As $U$ is unitary, this also implies $U_{1,n} = 0$ for $n \geq 2$ (rows must be normalized). We therefore have $$U = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & U' \end{pmatrix}.$$
As $U$ is unitary, $U'$ needs to be unitary as well. We conclude that these are exactly the matrices that satisfy your assumption. In particular, there are infinitely many. In fact, they even form a Lie group.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. In my question I specified that the eigenvalue had to be 1. Do you know if I can make a similar statement about the form of U if I allow $Uv=v$ to be true for a matrix with eigenvalue -1 and eigenvector -v? If I know that the EV is -1, then writing U in the basis of -v will yield the same form for U with $U_{1,1}=-1$. I am wondering if a general form of U can be given simply knowing the relation $Uv=v$?

Comment: I do not quite understand your question. $Uv = v$  is literally the definition of eigenvalue $1$. Are you asking what happens if you additionally demand that one eigenvalue is $-1$?

Comment: In my problem, there is a matrix for which $Uv=v$. However, when I compute the eigenvalues of this particular $U$, I find that it has the eigenvalue -1 with the corresponding eigenvector -v. I was unsure if this would change anything about the form of $U$ in the basis of $v$, but now that I think about it, it probably doesn't change anything. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: That cannot happen. If $Uv = v$, then $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. This also implies $U(-v) = -v$ by linearity, hence $-v$ is also an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$, not $-1$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I have found my mistake now.